# Output accuracy and loss from the same layer in caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, loss

I have written a custom layer and would like to output both the `accuracy` and `loss` at the same time. Is this possible to accomplish using `caffe` in the following manner ?

Something similar to :

```
layer {
name: ""
bottom: ""
top: loss1
top: loss2
top: accuracy
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many "top"s as you want for your layer.

First, you need to define the number of "top"s your layer computes. This is done by overriding [`ExactNumBottomBlobs()`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/layer.hpp#L217-L240).
Your `LayerSetup` and `Reshape` methods should also take into account the new number of "top"s and setup and reshape these "top"s as well.

Note that since your layer is a loss layer, you'll have to have [`loss_weight`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/86d451e96bda76878f81e6db426c651a440fa9ae/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L321-L324) value for each "top":

```
layer {
  name: "my_new_layer"
  type: "MyNewLayer"
  bottom: "x"
  top: "loss1"
  top: "loss2"
  top: "accuracy"
  loss_weight: 1
  loss_weight: 1.3 # you might want loss2 to have a bit more impact
  loss_weight: 0   # accuracy should not affect gradients...
}
```

And your layer class should be derived of `LossLayer<Dtype>` class, rather than the more abstract `Layer<Dtype>` class.

For more information on how to implement new layers in caffe, see [this page](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Development).
Also note that `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` layer has an optional second "top", you might want to look in the code of that layer to see how this is implemented.